# How to return an expected value with decimal places using dual table on Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently trying to force a number to have a two decimal character on the output no need to round,
if there is a decimal value exist I just need to have 2 decimal places

Example:

26 will return 26.00

26.1 will return 26.10

26.20 will return 26.20

26.09090909 will return 26.09

26.23090909 will return 26.23

0.14000 will return 0.14

0.04000 will return 0.04

0 will return 0.00

but the in-house language that I'm currently using has a very limited function to do it (possible but it will take a lot of lines). 
but I am able to do a query on Oracle SQL. Now I would like to ask if it is possible to query using the dual table on SQL.
My plan is to pass the value to variable and this variable will be use on my SQL command and SQL will return my expected value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(26, '99.99') AS X  FROM DUAL
```

For numbers less than 1 in which you need to have 0 explicitly you have to provide it like

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(0.14000,'0.99') FROM DUAL;
```

So you can use it like

```
CASE WHEN myNum > 0 and myNum < 1 
then TO_CHAR(myNum,'0.99') else 
TO_CHAR(myNum, '99.99')
```

or more simplified(*as suggested in comments*):

```
select to_char(num, 'fm9999999990.00') from dual
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it works correct with the whole number but with the value like 0.14000 it is omitting the zero it returns ".14"

Comment: @vic-rattlehead:- Updated my answer!

Comment: You don't need the case statement. Using a 0 in the format mask will always make a value be displayed even if it's zero, whereas 9 will only display a value if it is non-zero. So, by using a format mask of `fm90.00` you will ensure that all the necessary digits (but no extra spaces) are specified, providing the number is less than 100 and greater than -100. Include more 9's at the front of the format mask to cater for larger numbers.

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi The updated SQL query works.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need format mask:

```
select to_char(yourVariable, 'fm9999999990.00') from dual
```

According to Boneist's suggestion, 'fm' in format mask prevents the creation of blanks, while '0' digits are useful to always write the digit:

```
with test(num) as
(
select 26 from dual union all
select 26.1 from dual union all
select 26.20 from dual union all
select 26.09090909 from dual union all
select 26.23090909 from dual union all
select 0.14000 from dual union all
select 0.04000 from dual union all
select 0 from dual
)
select num, to_char(num, 'fm9999999990.00')
from test
```

Comment: You don't need `ltrim`; Oracle provide a way of doing it as part of the format mask, eg: `to_char(num, 'fm9999999990.00')`